# How many 12-length strings composed of only 0,1,2 contain exactly three 1s: why does the answer involve $12\choose 3$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The more intuitive answer to me is ($10$ multichoose $3$) * $2^9$, but the more common answer is ${12 \choose 3} * 2^9$. I realize these two evaluate to the same number and so they answer the same question, but I don't understand why the latter successfully answers the question. Could somebody reveal to me the line of thinking required to end up at the answer $(12$ choose $3$) * $2^9$ instead of $(10$ multichoose $3) * 2^9$?

---

As a note, here is why $12 \choose 3$ doesn't make sense to me and how I arrive instead at ($10$ multichoose $3$):
First, doing $12 \choose 3$ would imply that we couldn't choose the same position twice, i.e. we couldn't have multiple $1$s occur in a row with no $0$ or $2$ in between them.

Second, there are only $10$ positions between $9$ digits, as seen below using an example string:

$\_0\_0\_0\_0\_0\_0\_0\_0\_0\_$

There are $10$ underscores, each of which represent a possible location for a $1$.

So we have ($10$ multichoose $3$).

Clearly this line of thinking does not lead us to $12 \choose 3$. So what does?

Comment: Choose three places to put the ones.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Right, so there are $10$ places and we can choose each place more than once since ones can be adjacent. This gives us ($10$ multichoose $3$). But how do we get $12 \choose 3$?

Comment: What length of string are you considering?  It sounds like it could be $10$ but you never say.  Or is it $12?$

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah sorry that was a big oversight on my part, it's 12-length strings I'm considering. That's why there are 9 zeroes in my visualization of the available spots: we've chosen 9 of the 12 digits (none of which are 1) and we have to choose 3 spots (out of 10 possible spots) to put the ones.

Comment: What if you choose where to place the ones first? Then placed everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $12$ positions, you can place three $1$s among them in $12 \choose 3$ ways.  There is nothing in the problem about $10$ places or choosing a place more than once.  Once you have placed the three ones, you can fill the other $9$ places in two ways each, giving a factor $2^9$

Your approach works fine because you are placing the nine $0$s and $2$s first, then distributing the $1$s among them.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!